# Open software tool or QGIS plug-in to make land cover classification

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, classification

Is there any tool or plugin for QGIS/GRASS to make an automatic land cover classification from satellite imagery --- based on CLC nomenclature for example? Of course, it will not be 100% sure but it would be a first step of the classification process.

I have seen a similar tool expressed into a [pdf file](http://blog.qgis.org/files/Request%20for%20Proposal%20And%20Quotation%20for%20AILUM%20Plugin.pdf) on the QGIS blog, but it seems the plugin has not been implemented (at least, not listed into the plugin repository).

I have also the existence of the [Molusce plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/molusce/). I haven't tested it yet but the approach seems to be based on land use changes.

Comment: Do you need land use or land cover? Land use cannot be derived from satellite imagery alone.

Comment: Indeed, I mean land cover of course

Answer (score 4):

It will be very difficult to perform an automatic Land Cover Classification based on the 44 class Corine Land Cover nomenclature. but as you say it could be a starting point.

You can use the GrassGIS plugin for QGIS - check [this](http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/Image_classification)- namely for the spectral classification. Don't forget to integrate the ndvi.

Also you can try to perform a segmentation of the image first to have the image divided into 25ha polygons (MMU for CLC).

Then integrate the spectral classification into the polygons, i.e. classify the polygons accordingly to class of the majority of the matching pixels.

Regards,
Vasco Nunes